# Set domain on ordinal scale from tsv data

Tags: d3.js

I'm use d3js and loading in some data from a tsv file. For numeric data I'm setting the scales like this:

```
var x=d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return + d.GERD;}),d3.max(data,function(d){return +d.GERD;})])
      ...
```

Which find the min and max values in the actual data. This way I don't have to guess on my scale and if the data changes the scale changes.

I want the same thing for non-numeric values.

In this same data there is a "Continent" grouping that I want to color code for. So I'm using a category10 ordinal scale, like this:

```
var colorRamp=d3.scale.category10()
                 .domain(["Africa","Asia"....]);
```

All the examples I find on the web show the domain for ordinal scales being set with specific values and not how to pull that information from the data.

I fiddled around and came up with this which works:

```
var colorRamp=d3.scale.category10()
        .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.continent; }))
```

My question is, is this the best way to do this? Is there something more d3 idiomatic? Am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to define an ordinal scale, you generate an array from the data you have, much like you suggested:

```
var colorRamp = d3.scale.category10()
    .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.continent; }));
```

In your case, if you aren't sure of the order of your data it might also be valuable to sort the domain:

```
var colorRamp = d3.scale.category10()
    .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.continent; }).sort(d3.ascending));
```

Note that you don't technically need to set the domain on an ordinal scale; if you explicitly set the range of the data the domain is inferred from each unique value passed to the scale function [1].

[1] [D3 Ordinal Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales)

Comment: Thanks. I had noticed that it was assigned when I passed the data through. But I was trying to create a legend and found that it didn't work if I put the code before the charting. I figured that there would be times when I wanted to explicitly assign the domain -- so it is good to have in my bag of tricks.